# gpg 2.0 command line option to create UTF-8 data

Tags: gnupg, openpgp, unicode

With `echo text | gpg2 --sign --textmode -a` I can create messages with a one pass signature containing a Literal Data packet in TEXT ('t') format.

If I skip the `--textmode` option it will generate BINARY ('b') mode.

However according to [RFC 4880 Sec 5.9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.9) there is also a 'u' mode, which is basically text mode in UTF-8. Is there a way to generate this with GnuPG command line? (`--utf8-strings` or `--display-charset=UTF8` or `--charset=UTF8` had no effect when piping in a UTF-8 test file with *gpg4win-vanilla-2.3.0* containing *gpg2 2.0.29*).

Comment: It looks like not only the textmode, but especially the UTF8 textmode seem to not be used. I will stick with binary content for my usecase (as I am on both sides).